Issue with editing of text
I have issues with the editing of text and when any item text is tapped for editing, the textfield in the bottomModalSheet is supposed to be populated with the actual index of the item text but it isnt and Index error is always being thrown when any text is tapped
The function i used to handle the editing is given below
 void onEditTap(int index, BuildContext context) {
    
    final currentList = _showCompleted ? completedItems : uncompletedItems;

    
    if (index < 0 || index >= currentList.length) {
      print("Invalid index for current list: $index");
      return;
    }

    final item = currentList[index];
    final actualIndex = _toDoItem.indexOf(item);

    if (actualIndex == -1) {
      print("Item not found in main list: $item");
      return;
    }

    
    print(
        "Editing Item at Actual Index $actualIndex: ${_toDoItem[actualIndex]}");
    _isTextEditing = true;
    _editingIndex = actualIndex;
    
    _modalTextController.text = _toDoItem[actualIndex]["text"];

    fabKey.currentState?.showModalForEditing(
      context,
      isEditing: true,
      initialText: _toDoItem[actualIndex]["text"],
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }


Please provide the specific error it throws.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
